# In Javascript is it possible to create an object with dynamic (undetermined) properties/members?

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

I try to achieve this in Javascript:

```
var a = new MyObj();
console.log(a.Foo()); // Print Foo
console.log(a["Bar"]()); // Print Bar
```

Basically, I don't know beforehand the property/member name that is needed, but depends on the calling I return it, a bit similar to C# `ExpandoObject` (dynamic).

Is it possible to make such an object in Javascript?

Note: I know it is possible to *add* the properties, however, in my case I do not know beforehand which are needed to add.

```
a.Foo = () => { return "Foo"; }
```

This is not possible because I don't know `Foo` will be needed.

Comment: yes, it is possible. please add `MyObj`.

Comment: yes .... it will be Object.create(MYobjet)

Comment: sounds to me as if you want to fiddle with https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy it would allow you to do something like: `a.awdiawflhiawf()` wich would allow you to print `awdiawflhiawf`

Comment: @David sorry, added clarification.

Comment: @GottZ yes, this is what I was looking for, wonderful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and implement only a getters by returning a function which is a closure over the key.

```js
var a = new Proxy({ baz: 42 }, {
        get: function (target, prop, receiver) {
            return prop in target
                ? () => target[prop]
                : () => prop;
        }
    });

console.log(a.Foo());    // Foo
console.log(a["Bar"]()); // Bar
console.log(a.baz());    // 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i made a mistake, take a look at the snippet now; hope this is what you are looking into.

can you check the snippet now .:D

```js
let a = {}; // object
a.Foo = ()=> {return 'foo'};
a.Bar = ()=> {return 'bar'};

a.address = {}; // object inside object
a.address.houseno = '122';

console.log(a.Foo()); // Print Foo
console.log(a["Bar"]()); // Print Bar
console.log(a.address.houseno)
```

Comment: Sorry this is not what I needed (please see the clarification I added). I am not able to assign every property because I do not know them.

Comment: @LukeVo, is this what you looking for ?

Answer (score -2):

In modern browsers you can achieve that using [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

Here an example to achieve what you described:

```
const o = new Proxy({}, {
  get(obj, name) {
    return () => name
  }
});
```

In the specific case you don't have an original object you want to "proxy", but you probably want to read more on the link above for adding all the traps you want to.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: and i'm sitting here wondering why i wrote a comment instead of an answer. probably because this is not an answer.

Comment: Yes this is what I needed. I think I will suggest edit, copy part of the code from that page here.